# Find project in gitlab by ID

Tags: gitlab

How i can find a project in Gitlab by **ID**?
I found description to search by issue id `#123` and MR `!123` but not find by id

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned by [Daly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13752421/daly) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70862941/find-project-in-gitlab-by-id#comment132056199_70863048), you can browse to

```
https://gitlab.com/projects/{id}
```

and be redirected to the appropriate project.

Comment: a side note: you can also use this as a "search engine" in browser, e.g. by adding it as `https://gitlab.com/projects/%s` in Chrome as e.g. `gl`, you can then just do `gl 133769` in address bar to open GitLab project `133769` instantly etc.

Answer (score 5):

Have you read the API-docs?
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-single-project

```
GET /projects/:id
```

Comment: sorry, but i can't get any project, i tryed like this:
curl -X GET \
'https://gitlab.mycomp.ru/api/v4/projects/:id/' \
-H "PRIVATE-TOKEN=JR-4gferg564tg54" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{\"id\":\"7223\"}' | jq .

Comment: Have you tried to put the Id instead of `:id` into the URL? Your GET curl will work for any URL like `a/b/c?id=...`. Here you have to replace the `:id` instead

Comment: This also works via the browser by going to `https://gitlab.com/projects/:id` (and changing the domain name for a different instance of course)